# How to find whether eye is open or shut face detection algorithm Android

Tags: android, image-processing, face-detection, eye-detection

I am trying to detect whether eyes are open or shut in a detected face. I am using the following code for eye detection. What this code does is essentailly detect the distance between the eyes. Then it calculates the midpoint of the face and from there detects the centre of the eye and draws a circle around the eyes. That is the eye detection part.

However what I want to do is find whether the eyes are closed or shut.
How I want to do this is first of all find out how the eyes are detected / how the distance between the eyes is detected at a lower level and use that lower level code to decide whether eyes are closed or shut - i.e. I want to use this code's ability to detect the eye to find out how exactly does it do it and hence find out whether it is open or shut.
Could someone help me out please? I don't want to use opencv. I just want to use the simplicity of the code given below.

```
package my.eyedetector.code;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.content.Context;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

import android.graphics.Canvas;

import android.graphics.Color;

import android.graphics.Paint;

import android.graphics.PointF;

import android.media.FaceDetector;

import android.media.FaceDetector.Face;

import android.view.View;

public class EyeDetectorActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //setContentView(R.layout.main);

        setContentView(new myView(this));

    }



    private class myView extends View {



     private int imageWidth, imageHeight;

     private int numberOfFace = 4;

     private FaceDetector myFaceDetect; 

     private FaceDetector.Face[] myFace;

     float myEyesDistance;

     int numberOfFaceDetected;



     Bitmap myBitmap;

     public myView(Context context) {

        super(context);

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

         BitmapFactory.Options BitmapFactoryOptionsbfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();

         BitmapFactoryOptionsbfo.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565; 

         myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.mypic, BitmapFactoryOptionsbfo);

         imageWidth = myBitmap.getWidth();

         imageHeight = myBitmap.getHeight();

        myFace = new FaceDetector.Face[numberOfFace];

        myFaceDetect = new FaceDetector(imageWidth, imageHeight, numberOfFace);

         numberOfFaceDetected = myFaceDetect.findFaces(myBitmap, myFace); 

         }

         @Override

         protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

         // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, null);

             Paint myPaint = new Paint();

             myPaint.setColor(Color.RED);

             myPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); 

             myPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);



             for(int i=0; i < numberOfFaceDetected; i++) {

                 Face face = myFace[i];

                 PointF myMidPoint = new PointF();

                 face.getMidPoint(myMidPoint);

                 myEyesDistance = face.eyesDistance();

                 canvas.drawCircle((float)(myMidPoint.x - myEyesDistance/2.0), myMidPoint.y, (float)20.0, myPaint);

                 canvas.drawCircle((float)(myMidPoint.x + myEyesDistance/2.0), myMidPoint.y, (float)20.0, myPaint);

            }

         }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The face detection is basically using Haar cascade to find the eyes. Si its basically a set of weak feature detectors present there. You cannot detect the eyes closing or opening using this. You have to train your own eye close/open detector by training Haar cascade. Another easy way is just detect the pupil which is black and circle using Hough transform (if there  is enough resolution it might be possible).

Answer (score 0):

You can check the skin color of the zones around the eyes (on the left and on the right, to avoid eyebrows color). If it matches with the color of the eyes, maybe they are shut. Vice versa, the eyes are open.